# Execute JQuery on successful Captcha to replace div content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have been trying to replace the whole div containing the Captcha verification (Solvemedia). I am not sure how to do it. I am able to do it successfully on button click using JQuery's `replaceWith` function like this:-

```
<script>
$( "#btnCl" ).click(function() {
$("#2").css('display', 'block');
$( "div#1" ).replaceWith( $( "#2" ) );
});
</script>
```

It works properly and I have placed it before `</body>` But, I want the div to be changed after successful captcha verification. I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work:-

```
else {
//process form here
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#2").css('display', 'block');
$("div#1").replaceWith( $( "#2" ) );
</script>
<?php   
}
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

OK guys! It was a stupid mistake. The code I needed was:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#2").css('display', 'block');
$("div#1").replaceWith( $( "#2" ) );
});
</script>
```